# Click events are not available on the map of the react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{userList.map(v => (
    <Card
        key={v.user}
        onClick={() =>
            console.log("object")
        }
    >
        <Card.Header
            title={v.user}
            thumb={require(`../img/${v[tableName].avatar}.png`)}
            extra={<span>{v[tableName][extra]}</span>}
        />
        <Card.Body>
            {v[tableName].desc.split(/\n/g).map((v, k) => (
                <li  key={k}>{v}</li>
            ))}
        </Card.Body>
    </Card>
))}
```

Click events are not available on the `.map()` function in React

Comment: it is not clear what do you mean. please describe what do you expect and what happens instead.

Comment: i click Card , don't log "object",

Answer (score 1):

Card Component of React material UI does not support onClick props so you should not use it.
Quick Fix would be to enclose it inside a div and add onClick on the div as shown below:

```
<div onClick=> {() =>
               console.log("object")
             }>
    <Card>
     .....
    </Card>
</div>
```

Or You can use some different library from :
https://material-ui.com/api/card-action-area/